# How change variable bootstrap-scss

Tags: css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can not change variables bootstrap-sass in Laravel5.3 .
how can i do that?

content of app.scss file :

```
@import "_variables.scss";
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

I put my custom variables in variables.scss:

```
$screen-sm-min:880px;
```

then i run gulp in terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve it  ; the problem was in my gulpfile.js because I don't use Vue i had to

delete

```
require('laravel-elixir-vue-2');
```

from gulpfile.js

Answer (score 0):

Try importing your variables after the bootstrap scss. it works a lot like the normal css cascade. If you had a rule to "override" you would place it at the bottom of the document :)

Comment: Have you tried using an _ in the begining of your file name? @import "_custom-variables.scss"; As well as placing it after the other partials?